# Slider Color Configuration using CSS Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I want to customize the Google chart slider in control chart. The default setting for the slider label is the name of the column label; the slider thumbs as well as the min-max numbers are blue.
I want to do three things:
1) Customize the slider label 
2) Change the color of the slider thumbs
3) Change the color of min-max numbers

I have tried to see the documentation and tried the CSS class with no luck. For handling label issue (1), I do the following:

```
     var Slider1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
               'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter', 'containerId': 'filter1_div',
               'ui': {'label': 'Productive Area'},...., .....

                }
```

While for to handle questions no 2 and 3 (CSS part), I do the following:

```
    .sliderClass.google-visualization-controls-slider-thumb {
        background-color: #14894e;
        border: 1px solid #14894e;
        }
    .sliderClass.google-visualization-controls-rangefilter-thumblabel {
        color: #14894e;
        }
```

Is there anything more I supposed to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `sliderClass` is a class on the container div, all you should need to do is insert a space between `.sliderClass` and `.google...` in the CSS:

```
.sliderClass .google-visualization-controls-slider-thumb {
    background-color: #14894e;
    border: 1px solid #14894e;
}
.sliderClass .google-visualization-controls-rangefilter-thumblabel {
    color: #14894e;
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't change. Do I to add something more in the ui statement?

Comment: Can you update your question with a complete code sample that replicates the problem (including data and HTML), or create a jsfiddle/jsbin/etc that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the closest one is the example [link] (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#numberrangefilter). Look at the slider and text in the blue color. I want to change the text and slider thumb and thumb label colors.

Comment: I know my mistake; actually I forgot to add .sliderClass in the div container. Nothing wrong in the css statement. It works now. Thanks for being so helpful @asgallant

Comment: Question no 1 not yet answered, how to change the label. "Age" (next to the slider) is derived from the column label in the table. How to change it, say to "Age of Children". I try 'ui': {'label':'our label'},.... but nothing happened.

Comment: Perfect!!! This time my mistake is using quotes in 'ui' statement. When I remove it, it works too :-)